# Vale a pena usar Bootstrap com Angular 8?

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite,

Recentemente comecei a estudar Angular 8. Meu contato com Angular até então era praticamente 0. Hoje me deparei com uma dúvida.

Na maioria das vezes que li sobre o uso de jQuery com Angular, as pessoas desaconselharam o uso de ambos em conjunto.

Hoje, criando algo para conhecer um pouco melhor `Angular Router`, pensei em usar o Bootstrap pra deixar o conteúdo um pouco melhor. Até que me lembrei: Bootstrap depende de jQuery.

Minha dúvida é:

Vale a pena usar os dois em conjunto? Existe alguma alternativa melhor?
Tenho a impressão de que usando os dois vou estar apenas tornando o site mais pesado.

Obrigado.

Comment: Por que não usa a versão Angular do Bootstrap? A maioria das bibliotecas escritas com jQuery possuem versões reescritas em Angular/Vue/React.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou pesquisar sobre a versão pra Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não necessariamente precisará de jquery, alem do mais, o jquery é uma "biblioteca" gigantesca, o correto é separar apenas o que você vai usar.

apesar de chamarem o jquery de "biblioteca", a ideia inicial para ele, era ser um framework, assim como o bootstrap, que deveria ser um framework, ao longo do tempo fizeram um desmonte nele, então decretou o status de biblioteca de vez, ele possui algumas coisas que podem entrar em conflito com o angular, pois são parecidos em alguns pontos, nada que não possa ser contornado.

no mais, você não precisará do jquery, porque dá para fazer tudo o que ele faz com o angularjs, tudo dependerá do que pretendes desenvolver, o bootstrap pode sim ser usado, mesmo sem o jquery.

Lembrando que o jquery apenas simplifica o código, não é outra linguagem, assim como o ajax, continua sendo javascript da mesma forma.